# How to make OnClick events for points in a React Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I found this helpful link https://jsfiddle.net/5rz5r9ag/12/ which shows how you can get onclick events with the regular chart js. The problem with using this with react chart js  is that I can't access myLineChart object like they did in that example because that's not how you make a line chart in react. Instead my react currently looks more like this in the render function:

```
return (
      <Line
      data={this.state.chartData}
      options={{
        onClick: function(evt) {
          var element = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
          if(element.length > 0)
          {
            var ind = element[0]._index;
            if(confirm('Do you want to remove this point?')){
              data.datasets[0].data.splice(ind, 1);
              data.labels.splice(ind, 1);
              myLineChart.update(data);
              }
            }
        },
        ....
      />
);
```

I can't get access to the myLineChart in react like they can in the jsfiddle and thus can't figure out how to make an onClickevent for the points in my linechart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try second parameter of onClick :

```
return (
      <Line
      data={this.state.chartData}
      options={{
        onClick: function(evt, element) {
          if(element.length > 0)
          {
            var ind = element[0]._index;
            if(confirm('Do you want to remove this point?')){
              data.datasets[0].data.splice(ind, 1);
              data.labels.splice(ind, 1);
              myLineChart.update(data);
              }
            }
        },
        ....
      />
);
```

simple Line onClick : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-line-chart-js-r559n)

Comment: This will not work with multiple datasets.